# item instances or items instances?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm making a game that has items inside it and each items has its own instances. Then I have a DB table that contains those instances. What should I name it to properly indicate my case? ItemInstances or ItemsInstances? Thanks!

**Edit**

My table might looks like this:

```
id | itemId | location
1  | 1      | New York
2  | 1      | San Fransisco
3  | 2      | New York
4  | 2      | New York
```

So this table can contain any type of items with possibility of multiple amounts (instances) of each items.

Comment: Table names should be singular but naming things is off-topic here.

Comment: It looks like an *Instance Table* but this is not a matter of English usage. You could call it the “Instabin” if you so wished and if you defined it as such in your system.

Comment: You could call it table27 if you wanted, it wouldn't make any difference to the users who will never see either the table nor the name. It wouldn't be a good idea to use a non-meaningful name from a maintenence and development point of view but the grammar of table and variable names really makes little difference. A description of the table including its function and an entity relationship diagram, however, are a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

If there are several instances and to each instance there is one item, then *ItemInstances*.

If there are several instances and to each instance there is more than one item, then *ItemsInstances*.

I'm assuming that *Item(s)Instances* are collections of *Item(s)Instance*-s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Well to make it more clear, the table looks like on the edited :)